# Call method in class using dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a  .NET core web app which has the dependency set up:

```
    public class FooController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IFooRepository FooRepository;

        public FooController(IFooRepository fooRepository)
        {
            FooRepository = fooRepository;
        }
    }

    public class FooRepository : IFooRepository
    {
        private readonly IFooContext FooContext;

        public FooRepository(IFooContext fooContext)
        {
            FooContext = fooContext;
        }
    }

    public class FooContext : BaseContext, IFooContext
    {
        public FooContext(ApplicationDbContext appDbContext) : base(appDbContext)
        {
        }
    }
```

And everything works fine.

What i want to do is create a class which calls a method in the FooRepository without using IFooRepository in the constructor, Is this possible?:

```
  public class Bar
    {
        public Bar()
        {
             FooRepository.GetMyFoo();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? You _could_ have a static method. But I doubt it would make much sense?

Comment: Not with static (tight coupling) which defeats the whole purpose of using DI.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The only other options outside CTOR injection and static method that I see would be to a) create a new instance with `new` or b) resolve an instance from your DI container of choice. Which both are inferior to CTOR injection (if a) is at all possible).

Comment: **IF** it's about not giving away your complete `IFooRepository` interface to `Bar`, why not have FooRepository implement another interface and wire that up in DI, then inject that one?

Answer (score 0):

Just create another interface for the methods you want to "share". 
And do not forget to also add this interface implementation to you DI container.

Now your `IFooRepository` does not have the `GetMyFoo()` and the consumer of `IGetMyFooAble` does not know more than he needs.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGetMyFooAble FooRepository;

    public FooController(IGetMyFooAble fooRepository)
    {
        FooRepository = fooRepository;
        fooRepository.GetMyFoo();
    }
}

public class FooRepository : IFooRepository, IGetMyFooAble
{
    private readonly IFooContext FooContext;

    public FooRepository(IFooContext fooContext)
    {
        FooContext = fooContext;
    }

    public void GetMyFoo() { /* your stuff */ }
}


public interface IGetMyFooAble
{
    public void GetMyFoo();
}

public class FooContext : BaseContext, IFooContext
{
    public FooContext(ApplicationDbContext appDbContext) : base(appDbContext)
    {
    }
}
```